# How to override hibernate collection join column?

Tags: java, hibernate

This is my abstract father:

```
@MappedSuperclass   
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_no", referencedColumnName = "MY_COLUMN")
    private Set<CLASS_TYPE> list; 
}
```

All my entities has this set, but each entity has different `referencedColumnName`.

Is there a way to override only the `@JoinColumn` annotation?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [AssociationOverride](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/AssociationOverride) annotation. In your case it would look like this:

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
   @AssociationOverride(name = "list",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "COLUMN_NEW_NAME"))
})
public class ConcreteEntity extends AbstractEntity {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you define annotations on the properties (i.e. getters) instead of on the fields, then you can override the `public Set<CLASS_TYPE> getList()` in each of the sub classes and define the `@JoinColumn` separately.